# Python guessing game, my win condition prints win and loss

Tags: python

Im learning python and having a go at the guessing game. my game works but my win condition prints both "you win" and "you loss", I think my "if" statements are incorrect but i could be wrong.
Also, there's an issue with my printing of the win loss, I can only get it to print the loss..
Thanks in advance!

```
import random

print("Number guessing game")

name = input("Hello, please input your name: ")
win = 0
loss = 0

diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)

if diceRoll == 1:
    print("You have 1 guess.")
if diceRoll == 2:
print("You have 2 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 3:
    print("You have 3 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 4:
    print("You have 4 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 5:
    print("You have 5 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 6:
    print("You have 6 guesses.")

number = random.randint(1, 5)

chances = 0

print("Guess a number between 1 and 5:")

while chances < diceRoll:

    guess = int(input())

    if guess == number:

        print("Congratulation YOU WON!!!")
        break
        win += 1
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess was too low")

    else:
        print("Your guess was too high")

    chances += 1

if not chances == 0:
    print("YOU LOSE!!! The number is", number)
    loss += 1
print(name)
print("win: "+str(win))
print("loss: "+str(loss))
```

Comment: you enter the while loop, which increments `chances` and prints "you won", then you check `if not chances == 0` which is True, so you print "you lose" aswell.

Comment: Welcome! Good luck learning. If you read through what your code is doing you might notice that if you guess incorrectly then chances will be incremented by one, and then if you guess correctly you will break out of your loop, and then check if chances is not equal to 0.  You could reset chances to zero within the win loop. Also notice that you break statement is before your win increment, so you'll never have win += 1 execute.

Comment: one last problem, Im trying to print to a txt file but my new line gets an error:    stat.write(name + ":" + " win: "+str(win) + " loss: " +str(loss) +" chances: "+str(chances), ("\n"))    I want a new line after it prints but cant get the formatting correct

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your loop. Since you're breaking if it's correct, you can use a `while: else`. Otherwise you can win on your last chance and still get the lose message.

```py
while chances < diceRoll:

    guess = int(input())

    if guess == number:

        print("Congratulation YOU WON!!!")
        break
        win += 1
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess was too low")

    else:
        print("Your guess was too high")
    chances += 1
else:
    print("YOU LOSE!!! The number is", number)
    loss += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, so is should have used else.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop the if statement should be...

```
if guess == number:
    print("Something)
    win += 1
    break
```

and the last if statement should be...

```
if win != 0:
    print("You lose")
else:
    print("You win")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the final `if` statement. The player loses if their `chances` are greater than the `diceRoll`, whereas the if condition is true if the player's chances are not 0 i.e. the player failed once.

The code for the final if statement should look something like this:

```
if chances >= diceRoll:
    print("YOU LOSE!!! The number is", number)
    loss += 1
```

As for the problems printing the win, the problem here is in the first if statement inside the while loop. If the player wins the `break` statement is encountered first, so the code breaks out of the while loop without incrementing the `win` counter.

Just swap the `break` statement with the `win += 1` and it'll work wonders:

```
if guess == number:
    print("Congratulation YOU WON!!!")
    win += 1
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

To start look at

- the position of your break
- the loss condition